# Codeigniter 4 View file invalid

Tags: codeigniter-4

I am using codeigniter 4 with modules.I am getting error invalid file :Admin/valid_faq.php
What is wrong in the view path?
My Module structure is like below

```
app
 --modules
   -- Faq
      --controller
      --Models
      --Views
        --Admin
          --view_faq


    echo view('layout/header', $data);
    echo view('layout/sidebar');
    echo view('Admin/view_faq', $data);
    echo view('layout/footer');
```

I have gave the full path then also it doesn't work.

```
    echo view('App/Modules/Faq/Views/Admin/view_faq');
    echo view('Modules/Faq/Views/Admin/view_faq');
```

I have added to Autoload as well

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Modules'     => APPPATH . 'Modules',
];
```

When I checked the view file
`SYSTEMPATH\Common.php : 1121   —  CodeIgniter\View\View->render ( arguments )`

`F:\xampp\htdocs\modularcms\app\Config/../Views/Modules/Faq/Views/Admin/view_faq.php`

This is working

```
echo view('../Modules/Faq/Views/Admin/view_faq', $data);
```

my view directory   in the paths

```
 public $viewDirectory = __DIR__ . '/../Views';
```

Error function

```
public static function renderer(string $viewPath = null, $config = null, bool $getShared = true)
{
    if ($getShared)
    {
        return static::getSharedInstance('renderer', $viewPath, $config);
    }

    if (is_null($config))
    {
        $config = new \Config\View();
    }

    if (is_null($viewPath))
    {
        $paths = config('Paths');

        $viewPath = $paths->viewDirectory;
    }

    return new \CodeIgniter\View\View($config, $viewPath, static::locator(), CI_DEBUG, static::logger());
}
```

Comment: That can be cause of 'sentence case' of file and path name.

Comment: I did not get. Can you explain

Comment: Is your view filename view_faq or view_faq.php or view_faq.html ?

Comment: it is view_faq in the view

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear about your modules directory. Let’s say you want to keep a simple Faq module that you can re-use between applications. You might create folder with name, faq, to store all of your modules within. You will put it right alongside your app directory in the main project root:

```
/faq        // modules directory
/app
/public
/system
/tests
/writable
```

Open ***app/Config/Autoload.php*** and add the **Faq** namespace to the `psr4` array property:

```
$psr4 = [
    'Config'        => APPPATH . 'Config',
    APP_NAMESPACE   => APPPATH,                // For custom namespace
    'App'           => APPPATH,                // To ensure filters, etc still found,
    'Faq'          => ROOTPATH.'faq'
];
```

A common directory structure within a module will mimic the main application folder:

```
/faq
    /modules
        /Config
        /Controllers
        /Database
        /Helpers
        /Language
        /Libraries
        /Models
        /Views
            /Admin
               /view_faq
```

View:

```
echo view('Faq\Modules\Views\view_faq', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably already too late, but maybe others - like me - are looking for it. The solution was there for me:
Write the folder in the Views folder in lower case and put a double backslash behind it. So in your example:

```
echo view('Modules\Faq\Views\admin\\view_faq');
```