# Module view file showing invalid in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I've added the module folder in **...\app\Config\Autoload.php**

```
public $psr4 = [
          APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
          'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
          'Blog'      => ROOTPATH . 'example/blog',
];
```

**My directory:**

```
/Home directory of main project folder
/example
    /Blog
        /Config
            /Routes.php
        /Controllers            
            /Blog.php
        /Views
           /show_blog.php
```

**Routes.php**

```
namespace Config;

// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes();

$routes->get('blog', 'blog::index', ['namespace' => 'Blog\Controllers']);
```

**Blog.php**

```
namespace Blog\Controllers;

class Blog extends \CodeIgniter\Controller {

    function index() { 
        echo view('Example\Blog\Views\show_blog');
    }

}
```

After running **my_domain/index.php/blog**, it's showing this error:

```
CodeIgniter\View\Exceptions\ViewException

Invalid file: Example\Blog\Views\show_blog.php
```

Didn't get any solution from this one: [Codeigniter 4 View file invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64618618/codeigniter-4-view-file-invalid)

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing **Blog.php** to this, worked for me.

```
namespace Blog\Controllers;

class Blog extends \CodeIgniter\Controller {

    function index() { 
        echo view('Blog\Views\show_blog');
    }

}
```

Credit: CI Forum